# Cómo crear un nuevo documento en Firebase usando un ID personalizado mediante API REST?

Tags: firebase, api, flutter

Tengo definida la clase usuario de este tipo:

```
class Usuario{
  final String email;
  final String empresa;
  final String rol;

  Usuario(this.email, this.empresa, this.rol);
}
```

Al implementar el servicio de autenticación de Firebase, se genera un keyUserID que quiero usar como key para la creación de un nodo que almacene el email, la empresa y el rol dentro de la base de datos.

Por ejemplo, si el userID es "ABC123", quisiera que la base de datos quedara así:

```
{
  "usuarios" : {
    "ABC123" : { //Se usa ABC123 como ejemplo de lo que sería el keyUserId
       "email"   : "test@empresa.com",
       "empresa" : "Nombre de laEmpresa",
       "rol"     : "Administrador",
    }
  } 
}
```

Mediante una solicitud http que aparece más abajo logro crear el documento con los datos del usuario, pero generando un ID de forma dinámica y no usando la que quiero (p.e. ABC123)

```
  Future<bool> crearUsuario(UsuarioModel usuario, String keyUserId) async {

    final url ='$_url/usuarios.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
    final resp = await http.post(url, body: usuarioModelToJson(usuario)); 

      //usuarioModeltoJson contiene el string de los datos del usuario
      //el POST me permite crear con éxito los datos de usuario dentro de la base de datos, pero no 
      //con el key personalizado que quiero usar (llamado keyUserId dentro de los parámetros)

    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body); 
    print(decodedData);
    return true;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

La definición completa de la clase Usuario y del método usuarioModelToJson es la siguiente:

```
import 'dart:convert';

UsuarioModel usuarioModelFromJson(String str) => UsuarioModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String usuarioModelToJson(UsuarioModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UsuarioModel {
    UsuarioModel({
        this.empresa,
        this.email,
        this.rol,
    });

    String empresa;
    String email;
    String rol;

    factory UsuarioModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UsuarioModel(
        empresa: json["empresa"],
        email: json["email"],
        rol: json["rol"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "empresa": empresa,
        "email": email,
        "rol": rol,
    };
}
```

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta la petición que haces a Firestore para agregar el documento

Comment: Hola, la petición que estoy haciendo es la que aparece al final, esto es: final resp = await http.post(url, body: usuarioModelToJson(usuario)); donde el url

Comment: Pero tu mencionas Firebase, y estas usando una petición http directa, porque no usas el sdk de firebase? Busca en pub.dev

Comment: Ya tengo todo montado en Flutter con peticiones http usando la API REST de FIREBASE. Hasta ahora me ha funcionado bien, aunque no se si me de limitaciones más adelante

Comment: ok, muestra este método  usuarioModelToJson(usuario)  para ver el json que le envías

Comment: Ok... voy a actualizar la respuesta. El usuarioModelToJson lo hice de la forma fácil con quicktype

Comment: ahí puse mi respuesta, espero te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré es la siguiente:

**1. Incluir el keyUserId en el body**

Para mayor claridad voy a hacerlo con la variable stringBody:

```
final stringBody = '{"$keyUserId" : ${usuarioModelToJson(usuario)}}';
```

Como el body es un String de un JSON, debes tener cuidado con las comillas "", los dos puntos : y las llaves {}, justo como está indicado arriba.

**2. Cambiar el método POST por PATCH**

```
final resp = await http.patch(url, body: stringBody);
```

La razón del cambio es que cuando se usa POST Firebase genera un nuevo ID, de tal manera que el keyUserId se convierte en un hijo del ID generado por Firebase.

Con PATCH no pasa eso, y tampoco borra los demás usuarios que se han generado (como si pasaría con PUT).

**El código final del API REST para crear el usuario es el siguiente:**

```
  Future<bool> crearUsuario(UsuarioModel usuario, String keyUserId) async {

    final stringBody = '{"$keyUserId" : ${usuarioModelToJson(usuario)}}';
    final url ='$_url/usuarios.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
    final resp = await http.patch(url, body: stringBody);
    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(decodedData);
    return true;
```

Comment: Si puedes incluye la fuente de donde lo sacaste. Por cierto usando el api rest no pierdes el real-time? Que es lo que generalmente uno busca en firebase?

Comment: La fuente en realidad fue revisar cómo es un archivo JSON por dentro, el resto fue ensayo y error. Respecto a tu pregunta de Firebase, a cuál o cuáles características de real-time haces referencia?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmOF_07IayrTntevxtbUxDL&v=U5aeM5dvUpA&feature=emb_title

Comment: Hasta ahora no. Entendería que la diferencia entre el API REST y el SDK es simplemente que el API es una forma más estándar de acceder a la base de datos. La seguridad, el acceso en real time de múltiples dispositivos al tiempo, etc son propiedades que he visto bien hasta el momento. No he hecho pruebas con el Offline Access, lo cuál es clave, pero supongo que tambien debiera funcionar, no?

Comment: Lo del acceso offline no va a funcionar porque eso lo maneja el plugin internamente, si usas solo el API REST tu debes encargarte de gestionar todo el acceso offline

Comment: Oooooops... tienes algún link sobre eso?

Comment: Eso solo lo trae los frameworks de cada plataforma, me parece que flutter también lo soporta  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: Sería muy grave. Lo que he leido es que para que pueda implementarse el acceso Offline, no deben manejarse awaits ni transactions. Pero no sabía que si las solicitudes se hacen por REST pierdes esa propiedad tan importante, eso no lo he visto en ninguna parte de la dcumentación.

Comment: pero esa parte es un poco obvia, es por eso que existen los plugins, los plugins están basados en el REST api, pero añadiendole muchas cosas más para hacer la integración más sencilla y con nuevas funcionalidades, como la del acceso Offline y el realtime, el realtime es cuando estas en una pantalla con una lista de datos, luego alguien cambia esos datos ya sea en la consola o desde otro dispositivo, entonces los cambios se reflejan automaticamente en tu pantalla sin recargar nada.

Comment: Ese realtime que mencionas se obtiene sin problema usando el API REST, ya lo he probado varias veces. En realidad, quienes lo controlan son los Streams en Flutter.